# the bash scripts returns status -13

Tags: python, bash, centos, subprocess

**Scenario:**  Below are two scripts where a bash script is invoked by python script.

test.py

```
import subprocess
p=subprocess.call(['bash','test.sh'])
f = open("demofile2.txt", "a")
f.write(p)
f.close()
```

test.sh

```
echo "hello world"
```

**observation:**
works fine when the test.py is executed directly.

**issue:**
when I create demon under /service to run the file. The value of 'p' (return of call) is -13.

Note: The user:group for both script is root. I am using centos8

Comment: On Nix-Line systems, hence including Centos, the exit code of a process can't be negative. Hence, the return value is what the Python function `call` returns, and not the exit code of a script. I have never used this Python function, but the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) say that if your called script has a non-zero exit code,  you get an exception of type `CalledProcessError` and can get the exit code from there.

Comment: @user1934428 even if I have empty sh file, I face a similar issue.

Comment: @Singh : That's what I said ..... You don't fetch the exit code of the called process in your program, and therefore it does not make sense to talk about the exit code. From what I see, the script is exiting with code 0.

Comment: @Jens : `p` is the Python variable where the return value from `call` is stored.  The OP is doing a `p=subprocess.call(['bash','test.sh'])`.

Comment: @jens p is used to write on file so that , i can see when demon runs what value it returns

Comment: It's not clear you what you mean by "daemon under /service", you should clarify that! At a first glance "A negative value -N indicates that the child was terminated by signal N (Unix only)." and 13 is SIGPIPE, my guess is that you are trying to write to a closed STDOUT, but without more info about the daemon mode I can't tell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has same problem, the answer lies in the resolution of the path.

When I to execute the python script in the command line, it was able to locate the script.
But when the demon tool (even systemd) runs the script it was not able to locate the bash script. When I provided absolute path of the bash script(opt\test\test.sh) in the python script,it worked.

\opt\test\test.py

```
import subprocess
p=subprocess.call(['bash','opt\test\test.sh'])
f = open("demofile2.txt", "a")
f.write(p)
f.close()
```

\opt\test\test.sh

```
echo "hello world"
```